# Curl bash to same server with https

Tags: bash, ssl, curl, https

I have make a request to url from the same server with a cron task. In the past I did this with the next bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl "http://www.mydomain.es/myfolder/importTwitter" >> /var/log/mydomain/import_twitter.log
```

I migrated the website to https and the curl command fails returning the next error:

```
* About to connect() to www.mydomain.es port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I have tried to add the next parameters to the curl command, and get the same error:

```
--cacert -> specify ssl ca root certificate
--cert -> specify ssl pem certificate
--location -> using the http url and force to follow redirects
--insecure -> allows insecure curl connections
```

Finally I also have tried make the request from another host and works fine, but I have do the request from the same server.

The server have Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64

Curl version:

```
curl 7.26.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `* Connection refused`

You've got your problem right there. Long before anything with crypto can start, your server simply does not allow a connection from your host.

Make sure your server is configured correctly and that no firewall is blocking loopback connections to port 443.